# surrogate keys as foreign key

Tags: database, database-design

Is setting the foreign key as surrogate of the parent table expense ?

Since I have to join that parent /reference table to show the natural key.

But why it is the best to set the foreign key as surrgate for referencing table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is expensive in a sense that you'd need a JOIN in some situations where it would not be necessary with the natural key (as you already noted). Also, natural keys usually play better with [clustering](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index), and are sometimes necessary for [correctly modelling diamond-shaped dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9082972/533120).

On the other hand, using a "skinnier" surrogate key can save some space and simplify updating (especially when there are several levels of FKs).

Neither approach is absolutely "better" - It's a matter of compromise.