# Is it better to have userID or username in updatedBy field in database

Tags: mysql, database-design, symfony, doctrine-orm, data-modeling

I have fields in my almost all tables like `createdBy` or `updatedBy`.
I think that's just for reference.

Do you think I should enter username there or `userID`. Because if i need to look at database directly then that can give better understanding or it's a bad practice.

Comment: userid because you'll find it easy to relate and follow this for all your tables or else you wont be able to join using these fields

Comment: Always the user ID as it is the one reference to the user account that will never change (presumably if you have a separate user name field, that one *can* change)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

always use foreign keys to store referential records, that is userID in your case.

and regarding the approach on how to store, it depends on what you need.

> a) if you want to know who last updated the record. then you should
>   create a `userID` column in the table.

it is always good to store foreign keys instead of other records, because this way you can relate and fetch all the records of a user. this approach will have a limitation though, since you can store only one userID, you can only know who last updated it.

> b) if you want to store all the records, to know which user updated
>   the records and when, then you should store it in one to many
>   relationship table. for example

`user_log with columns user_id, update_datetime` and perhaps a message column, telling what did the user do.

Answer (score 0):

UserID.
Because they are smaller and faster than usernames.

suppose your users want to change the username then you will not need to update all tables which is extremely efficient

Answer (score 0):

always use ID's to keep a normalized relational data structure.  this will provide better performance and much more scalability.    If you can include constraints it will make it that much more cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always bad. Defends on you application need. Normalisation is good to remove redundency. Whereas if speed is the factor you can keep it as it is. As join takes time. Also inserting data means inserting into two tables.

Never the less, always +1 for normalisation, by the book :)

Comment: The table `(USER_NAME PK, other fields...)` is not less "normalized" than `(USER_ID PK, USER_NAME AK, other fields...)`. Surrogates are not really about normalization - they are about practical implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Use something that cannot be changed later. Usually that is true of the user_id.

In special cases you may want to store the name in *addition* (to be able to display the name of the user at the time, before she married, or the name of a user that has since been deleted). But normally, you query the database again for the (current) name (which can also be cached easily).

Answer (score 0):

In the case of usernames, surrogate keys tends to be a better choice. So, in your case, FKs (`createdBy` and `updatedBy`) will reference the surrogate key (`userID`) and not the natural key (username).

However, this *doesn't* mean surrogate is *always* better than natural key: consider [this list of criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639189/533120).