# one to many annotation mapping with composite key

Tags: database-design, annotations, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables as mentioned below. The point is to have 'n' choice for my question. I have designed to have composite key on the second table instead of having one more column for primary key. With this approach i have two questions.

1. Is this a good approach in table design? i mean TABLE QUESTIONCHOICE has composite key rather than a primary key.
2. How do i make one to many mapping in Hibernate between QUESTIONBANK and QUESTIONCHOICE tables using annotations?

Any points and suggestions will be of great help.

Thanks,

-Vijay Selvaraj

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTIONBANK(
    QUESTIONID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT(10001, 1),
    QUESTION VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    TOPIC VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    SUBTOPIC VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    COMPLEXITY SMALLINT  NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    QUESTIONTYPE SMALLINT  NOT NULL,
    VERSION INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT QUESTIONBANK_PK PRIMARY KEY (QUESTIONID)
);

CREATE TABLE QUESTIONCHOICE(
   QID INT NOT NULL,
   CHOICE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   CORRECT_CHOICE BOOLEAN, 
   VERSION INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   CONSTRAINT QUESTIONCHOICE_PK PRIMARY KEY (QID, Choice),
   CONSTRAINT QUESTIONCHOICE_FK FOREIGN KEY (QID) REFERENCES QUESTIONBANK (QUESTIONID)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer the first half of your question...

> 1. Is this a good approach in table design? i mean TABLE QUESTIONCHOICE has composite key rather than a primary key.

This is not an either-or proposition. You have a key that happens to be **both** composite and primary.

Whether your design is valid depends on a whether a same value of `CHOICE` should be able to exist in multiple `QUESTIONCHOICE` rows (connected to different questions):

- If yes, your design is correct.
- If no, it's incorrect and you should make the `CHOICE` alone a key.

Whether to also add a surrogate key is a matter of balance, and here are [some criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639189/533120) to help you make a decision.

Comment: Thanks your reply answers my first question. and the second part of implementation is tricky :)