# A new column as primary key or use two FK as PK

Tags: database-design, primary-key, composite-primary-key

I have the following database design:

[image: Pk]

And I'm wondering if **EReportReq** must have a column as a primary key, **eReportReqId**, or maybe I can use **eReportId** and **requirementId** as **primary key**.

**Requirement** table will have system information and **EReport** table (which is not shown here), **EReportReq** and **EReportReqImg** will have user data.

**EReportReq** represents requirement which are part of an EReport. A requirement could be part of more than one EReport.

And **EReportReqImg** represents images (one or more) for those requirement that are part of an EReport.

Do I need **eReportReqId** as primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming an `EReport` cannot be connected to the *same* `Requirement` more than once, `{eReportId, requirementId}` is a key *in any case*. The only question is: do you need an *additional* surrogate key (`eReportReqId`)? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639189/533120) are some criteria that might help you decide.

My personal hunch is that the answer to that question is "no", so you'll end-up with a model like this:

[image]

This model allows for less JOINing in some cases. For example, getting all images of given `EReport` can be sattisfied by just scanning the `EReportReqImg` - the `eReportId` is already there so we can use it directly to filter data (instead of having to JOIN with `EReportReq` just to get the `eReportId`).

It also nicely [clusters](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering) the data in indexes (and potentially whole tables if your DBMS supports it) making certain range scans very efficient (including the one mentioned above).

Comment: Yes, an EReport cannot be connected to the same Requirement more than once. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* eReportReqId as a primary key for your table, though in some cases you would want it to have it's own primary key.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the FKs in **EReportReq**.  If the combination of the FKs **eReportId** and **requirementId** must be unique in **EReportReq**, then of course you could generalize it and use the FKs as the primary key of **EReportReq**.  Otherwise, you will need a separate column (i.e. **eReportReqId**) for the primary key.

*As a side note, if you were going to generalize it and use the FKs as the primary key, maybe you should consider normalizing the EReportReqImg table into EReportReq too.*

Comment: I'm so sorry, I've forgotten to say that a requirement for an E-Report could have more than one image. Thanks for your answer.