# How to design relationships between M-M tables in sql

Tags: sql, database-design

If I have a `match table ( id , details)` and `team table (id,name)`  and I want to get all matches played by a given two teams.

My solution is:

Create a third table contains on `(match_id,team1_id,team2_id)`

Is this the best practice in this case ?

Comment: creating third table would be a great idea. question, what do you mean `get all matches played by a given team`? do you mean that you only want match_ID where in it is both played by two teams or played by either of the two team?

Comment: The match id of a play played by both of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a match can be played only by two tables, the team1_id and team2_id should be part of the `match` table itself as attributes. A separate table is not needed. You can also define FOREIGN KEY relationship between team1_id and team table's id and the same for team2_id also.

A third table would be needed for a match that can be played by multiple teams and in such case the table structure would be (`match_id`, `team_id`) where there will multiple records with same match_id, i.e. one-to-many relationship between match table and match_teams table.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a third table - reference the teams directly from the `match` table:

[image]

Just to clarify, the `{team1_id, team2_id}` should **not** be a key, to allow the same pair of teams to be engaged in more than one match. And of course, it goes without saying you need appropriate FKs and a `CHECK(team1_id <> team2_id)`.

To get the matches played by the given team, you'd need..

```
SELECT ... WHERE team1_id = :given_team_id OR team2_id = :given_team_id
```

...so you need indexes on both team IDs, as denoted by `I1` and `I2` in the diagram above.

Also, consider making these indexes wider for performance reasons. For example, if your only fetch a limited subset of fields...

```
SELECT team1_id, team2_id FROM ...
```

...and widen the indexes to [cover](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) these fields (`I1: {team1_id, team2_id}` and `I2: {team2_id, team1_id}`), the DBMS won't have to touch your table heap at all to satisfy the query.

---

Alternatively, you could consider using a natural key, for example:

[image]

This would allow you to eliminate one of the indexes (the one under the surrogate PK: `{match_id}`), but would of course make any downstream FKs "fatter", which [may or may not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11639189/533120) be a good thing depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Depending on your querying needs, you may fiddle with the order of PK fields:

- For example, if majority of your queries ask: "give me matches played in the last X days", consider moving `match_date` to front.
- If majority of your queries ask for matches played at any time, keep it in the back.
- If both, then you'd need an additional index.

---

BTW, having a third table `{match_id, team_id}` is appropriate for matches that can be played by more than two teams (such as sailing). It also has an unfortunate feature of allowing only one or even zero teams - which is something you'll probably need to guard against in a non-declarative manner.

The design above ensures there are exactly two teams.