# Adding (or not) a FK to make a SELECT simpler

Tags: database-design, foreign-key-relationship

I'm developing an Android application and JSON web services. Android application will consume those web services.

Also, I will have a database on both sides, and server side and client side will have the same Database schema.

I will explain what I'm trying to do:

- Users create one **EReport** or more.
- Every **EReport** has one **QAP**. **QAP** table will be a copy of
  server side database.
- Every **QAP** has one or more **Defect**. **Defect** will be a copy
  of server side database.
- A user can define defects if he or she needs it. To do it, I have
  added **EReportDefect** table.
- A **Defect** could have one or more photos. I create
  **EReportDefImg** to store the relation between an EReport, and EReportDefect and one or more images.

My question is: Do I need **eReportId** as FK on **EReportDefImg**?

I've added that column because I could use to find all defect's images for an EReport.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need eReportId as FK on EReportDefImg?

No.

The `EReportDefImg.eReportId` would allow an `EReportDefImg` row to reference a `EReportDefect` row such that `EReportDefect.eReportId` is different from `EReportDefImg.eReportId`.

> I've added that column because I could use to find all defect's images for an EReport.

You can still do that (without `EReportDefImg.eReportId`) by JOINing `EReportDefImg` and `EReportDefect` to get the `EReportDefect.eReportId`.

If you want to avoid the JOIN, you can use the identifying relationship to include the `eReportId` in the `EReportDefect`'s PK, which would then also migrate it to `EReportDefImg.eReportId` (which you could then use directly for filtering, without JOIN). Ditto for `defectId`.

[image]

NOTE: I added `eReportDefectNo` to allow multiple `EReportDefect`s for the same combination of `EReport` and `Defect`. If that's not needed, remove the `eReportDefectNo`.

---

BTW your model, as it is now, allows for a single `EReportDefect` to be connected to two different `QAP`s (one through `EReport` an the other through `Defect`). Is that intentional?

Comment: With two different QAP? No, it isn't intentional. A defect can only belong to a QAP.

Comment: @VansFannel Then you'd need to use identifying relationships in higher levels of your model as well, like explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12350763/533120).

Comment: I've read what you've suggested me but I don't understand anything (maybe because of my English level). How can I avoid that "problem" on my design? Thanks.

Comment: @VansFannel Well, try to imagine what would happen if you try to insert at the bottom of the diamond. Without identifying relationships, sides of the diamond could point to whatever they like, including different tops. With identifying relationships, the top PK is propagated to the very bottom, so both sides must match it (lest side-to-bottom FK is violated), so they cannot differ in their choice of the top.

Comment: Ok, so I need to propagate qapId to every table, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The human logic says if there is a reportdefect there must be a report. so use the FK. I think this will maybe help you later.

Comment: I'm so sorry but I've made a terrible mistake. My question is: Do I need **eReportId** as FK on **EReportDefImg**? Sorry.

Comment: Ah ok, so my Answer is: NO ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't, this kind of design is performed usually for performance reasons - omiting unnecessary joins. If you don't have such a problem, than don't do this.

By the way, you seem to put too many foreign keys into primary keys. This is done to help maintain data consistency, but usually it is not a good practise due to performance degradation.

Btw. what is the defectId foreign key in EReportDefect for?

Comment: `EReportDefect.defectId` id a FK to `Defect` table. It will contain null because `EReportDefect` can contain user's defined `Detect`. This question is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425606/two-tables-almost-identical.