# Two tables almost identical

Tags: database-design

I'm developing an Android application and JSON web services. Both sides will have a database, and both of them will have the same database schema.

On client side, **Order**, QAP and Defect are a copy from server side database. I can't add more rows to those tables.

User will have a form with defect name and four columns: `CRS`, `CRF`, `MA` and `MI`. On these four columns user will insert some values. Defect's name is `Defect.description`, and CRS, CRF, MA and MI values will be part of current **E-Report**.

To store these values (CRS, CRF, MA and MI) I use **eReportDefect**.

My problem is that user can add more defects. If I could add more rows on **Defect** table, I won't have a problem, but I can't. To solve it I have added **UserDefect** table but I'm not sure if this is a good approach because I have two tables, **eReportDefect** and **UserDefect**, almost identical.

And I have "another problem" for every Defect filled in an EReport, I could have zero, one or more images (tables **eReportDefImg** and **UserDefImg**).

Is this design "OK" or it could be improved?

[image]

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your model in terms of normalization.  You need to distinguish between a defect and a user defect.  Only you can tell us if your model describes the relationships between the entities correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see some "old school" approach in primary key definition. ;-) Regarding the table `eReportDefect` your key is redundant, because as I understand "`defectId`" is already unique, so "`qapId`" and "`eReportId`" will only cause an index to be bigger thus slower - also the column positions in that case aren't the best. It is correct within `Defect` and `DefectImg` tables, while the same mistake is within `eReportDefImg`.

Ok, back to the point, if you can't modify `eReportDefect` table there is no other way like create another table.

Another thing, images. If I understand correctly you are able to modify table `eReportDefImg`, so there is no need for `UserDefImg` table and even for Image table. Instead of those three tables you can use one `DefectImg` table having:

```
PK image_id
FK userDefectId
FK defectId
```

If `userDefectId` IS NULL, then `defectId` IS NOT NULL and points to `eReportDefect`, and the other way around. This will save you storage and time consuming joins through `UserDefectImg` and `eReportDefImg` table. Those would be actually needed if one image could fit into more than one defects.